# How to do a live midi streaming?

Tags: midi

I'm looking for help in my research

I'm trying to generate live midi so that people can listen to it via a web browser

I'm not sure but I'm guessing there must be a way to set up a midi server to accept connections from my desktop with midi sequencer , sending that midi data to an online midi server where people can connect to and listen to the midi that is generating live right in their web browser

any help appreciated

Comment: I think that OSC is probably better suited to your needs here

Comment: @NikReiman, How do you propose using OSC in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to be better off writing a plugin to handle this.  That being said, it *is* possible to dynamically play MIDI with JavaScript.  See this question:  [generating MIDI in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761504/generating-midi-in-javascript)

You could read in the data just like any feed from your web server, and play it back in chunks.